# pyconfig-64.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, slackware

I have a newish Slackware 14.1 64-bit install (Python 2.7.5), and am trying to install pygraphviz via pip.

When I run:

```
pip install pygraphviz
```

however, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:124:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:6:25: fatal error: pyconfig-64.h: No such file or     directory
 #include "pyconfig-64.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The referenced pyconfig.h file is:

```
#include <bits/wordsize.h>

#if __WORDSIZE == 32
#include "pyconfig-32.h"
#elif __WORDSIZE == 64
#include "pyconfig-64.h"
#else
#error "Unknown word size"
#endif
```

Looking around, there is a lot of info for missing a pyconfig.h file, but not the 64 variant, and I'm struggling to find the package to install to take care of this. I tried to use rpm2tgz and the python-devel rpm for 2.7.5 from Fedora, but it didn't take care of the issue. Also, as I'm running slack, a yum or apt-get command isn't a valid solution, I need to know where I can find the actual package.

Comment: On my Fedora 20 system `rpm -q -f /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig-64.h` returns `python-libs-2.7.5-9.fc20.x86_64`.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks.

Comment: @JackGibbs So what was your solution to this? rpm2tgz'ing `python-libs-2.7.5-9.fc20.x86_64.rpm` and then installing?

Answer (score 2):

to solve problem you need to install python dev pakege

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```